# How to optimize Redis-server for high-load?

Tags: linux, redis, debian, high-load

Server: `Intel® Core™ i7-3930K 6 core, 64 GB DDR3 RAM, 2 x 3 TB 6 Gb/s HDD SATA3`

OS (uname -a): `Linux *** 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Redis server 2.8.19`

On the server to spin Redis-server, whose task is to serve requests from two PHP servers.
Problem: The server is unable to cope with peak loads and stops processing incoming requests or makes it very slowly.

Which attempts to optimize server I made:

```
cat /etc/rc.local
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
ulimit -SHn 100032
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse

cat /etc/sysctl.conf
vm.overcommit_memory=1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=65536
net.core.somaxconn=32768
fs.file-max=200000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1

cat /etc/redis/redis.conf
tcp-backlog 32768
maxclients 100000
```

What are the settings I found on `redis.io`, which is in blogs.

Tests

```
redis-benchmark -c 1000 -q -n 10 -t get,set
SET: 714.29 requests per second
GET: 714.29 requests per second

redis-benchmark -c 3000 -q -n 10 -t get,set
SET: 294.12 requests per second
GET: 285.71 requests per second

redis-benchmark -c 6000 -q -n 10 -t get,set
SET: 175.44 requests per second
GET: 192.31 requests per second
```

By increasing the number of customers is reduced query performance and the worst thing, Redis-server stops processing incoming requests and servers in PHP there are dozens of types of exceptions

```
Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message 'Connection closed' in [no active file]:0\n
Stack trace:\n
#0 {main}\n  thrown in [no active file] on line 0
```

What to do? What else to optimize? How do such a machine can pull customers?

Thank you!